# Method calling a function that takes a String and returns Unit

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a method that can take a function of type (String) => Unit. This does not seem to work.

```
  val sayHelloToPerson : (String) => Unit = (s : String) => { println("Hello  " + s) }
```

This works if i call

```
sayHelloToPerson("Mark")
```

But if I call it from a method like below

```
  def executeAnyFunction (f: (String) => Unit) = {
    f()
  }


  executeAnyFunction(sayHelloToPerson("Mark"))
```

the compiler says,

```
type mismatch, expected: String => Unit, actual: Unit.
```

Isn't the function itself of type `(String) => Unit`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. `executeAnyFunction` can only execute functions `String => Unit`. So not any function? Also, you're not providing the necessary string parameter to `f`, so what is the purpose of `executeAnyFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing that when defining executeAnyFunction, you are invoking the function f, without any parameter, hence the compiler failure.

What yo should do is return f, but without calling it (without parentheses):

```
def executeAnyFunction (f: (String) => Unit) = {
        f
}
```

Then you can use your new function as follows

```
  executeAnyFunction(sayHelloToPerson)("Mark")
```

Where `executeAnyFunction(sayHelloToPerson)` is the same as `f` and you give it a parameter `("Mark")`

Quick example here:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screen shots. (This one is close to unreadable.)

Comment: @jwvh I don't think it's "close to".

Answer (score 0):

Because you call you second method with application of function.

try `executeAnyFunction(sayHelloToPerson)`

and change body in order to pass `String` parameter to `f`. e.g.

```
def executeAnyFunction (f: (String) => Unit) = {
  f("Mark")
}


executeAnyFunction(sayHelloToPerson)
```

Comment: This way he needs a different executeAnyFunction for each different String. I think is better to return the function f as such, and then call executeAnyFunction with the desired String as a parameter

Comment: Probably.. or not. I do not know if it is a real-life example, or just learning example, so I tried to point to the difference between function and its application (and between functional type and function result type), which looks not clear to @Srinivas based on question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant:

```
def executeAnyFunction(f: (String) => Unit)(s: String) = f(s)

executeAnyFunction(sayHelloToPerson)("Mark")
// prints "Hello  Mark"
```

This defines `executeAnyFunction` as a function with two parameter lists: one with the function to execute, and another with the input for that function.

Still, not sure how `executeAnyFunction` has any value other than an educational one.